# posting to XML soap service and having a hard time getting the server response

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

The code throws a 500 html error response when it gets to the line using `(WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;

public partial class RawService : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static string _url = "https://iserv.intecon.co.za/allpsws_test/allps.asmx";
    static string _action = "https://iserv.intecon.co.za/allpsws_test/allps.asmx";
    static string _inputPath = @"C:\intercon\input.xml";
    static string _outputPath = @"C:\intercon\output.xml";
    static string _soapEnvelope =
@"<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<soap:Body></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        return webRequest;
    }

    private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope(string content)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(_soapEnvelope);
        sb.Insert(sb.ToString().IndexOf("</soap:Body>"), content);

        // create an empty soap envelope
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(sb.ToString());

        return soapEnvelopeXml;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText(_inputPath);
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope(content);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
        InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

        // begin async call to web request.
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

        // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
        // do something usefull here like update your UI.
        asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        // get the response from the completed web request.
        string soapResult;
        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        File.WriteAllText(_outputPath, (soapResult));
    }

    private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
    }

}
```

all i need to do is get the service response so that i can be able to use the methods

Comment: Why do url and action have the same values? Is that a typo? And what's in input.xml? 500 is thrown by server so it's hard to say anything by looking at the client code? Do you have the code for that web service? Maybe you can debug that or add some logging or check the existing ones

Comment: input has nothing.. the response will be stored in that path and folder and as for the url and action, i have no action to put there and it seems to go through when i use the same path for the url and the action. the web service has no WSDL document, all i have are samples of the request and response to work on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SOAP action appears to be wrong. If you look at the schema here (https://iserv.intecon.co.za/allpsws_test/allps.asmx?op=Call) you can see it's expecting

```
SOAPAction: "http://intecon.co.za/webservices/allps/Call"
```

Have a play with Fiddler (or something akin) and try to make sure you can get the call working outside of your code.

Using this header:

```
Host: iserv.intecon.co.za
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://intecon.co.za/webservices/allps/Call"
Content-Length: 364
```

And this body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Call xmlns="http://intecon.co.za/webservices/allps/">
      <xmlrequest></xmlrequest>
    </Call>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I get a 200 OK response - albeit it looks like there's an issue with the system I'm calling, possibly because I don't know what the XMLRequest I should be passing should look like.

EDIT: throwing some code together as an example:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    HttpWebRequest request = ( HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create( "https://iserv.intecon.co.za/allpsws_test/allps.asmx" );

    request.Headers.Add( "SOAPAction", "http://intecon.co.za/webservices/allps/Call" );
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    request.Accept = "text/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";

    XmlDocument soapRequest = CreateEnvelope();

    using ( Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream() )
    {
        soapRequest.Save( stream );
    }

    HttpWebResponse webResponse = ( HttpWebResponse )request.GetResponse();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( webResponse.GetResponseStream() );

    string response = reader.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine( response );
}

private static XmlDocument CreateEnvelope()
{
    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDocument.LoadXml( @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                          <soap:Body>
                            <Call xmlns=""http://intecon.co.za/webservices/allps/"">
                              <xmlrequest></xmlrequest>
                            </Call>
                          </soap:Body>
                        </soap:Envelope>" );

    return xmlDocument;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me how youi coded it out if u dont mind please.. as in share the whole code and structure, and the request should look like this:

Comment: <OpenAsi>
<uid>test</uid>
<pwd>tset</pwd>
<machine>pc_name</machine>
<user_if>allps-­‐ws</user_if>
<integrator>SomeSoft</integrator>
<product>ThisProd</product>
<version>1.0.0.1</version>
</OpenAsi>
</methods>. and this is to authenticate the whole session and get the methods to allow me to send through information.

Comment: <Call
xmlns="http://intecon.co.za/webservices/allps/"><xmlrequest><methods>
<OpenAsi> <uid>intellicellWS</uid>
<pwd>*******</pwd>
<machine>name</machine>
<user_if></user_if>
<integrator>SomeCompany</integrator>
<product>SomeProduct</product><version>1.0.0.1</version>
</OpenAsi>
</methods></xmlrequest></Call> thats what the input xml has

Comment: I didn't code it out. I used Fiddler to make a raw HTTP request with those values I posted to see if I could get a response from the server. Let me see if I can throw together some code for it.